# Specifying style on T-SQL convert function causes error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which takes in dates in a variety of formats and converts them to datetimes. The following line works just as expected:

```
RETURN CONVERT(datetime,@vMonth+'/'+@vDay+'/'+@vYear)
```

However, I want to specify that the date should always be treated as being in US format, as this will return the wrong result if T-SQL is set to use British. If I do this:

```
RETURN CONVERT(datetime,@vMonth+'/'+@vDay+'/'+@vYear, 101)
```

Then I start getting the following error (on all values I've tried):

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I've done a search and none of the threads that mention this error seem to be the same problem. I'm confused as to why specifying us_english (101) for a string that's already being converted as us_english causes the procedure to break.

Edit: I've boiled this down to a minimum case that shows where I'm not understanding.

This works:

```
select CONVERT(datetime,'01/02/03')
```

This does not:

```
select CONVERT(datetime,'01/02/03',101)
```

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs and the data types of the parameters?

Comment: `select convert(datetime,'01' + '/' + '09' + '/' + '2015',101)` works fine for me.  I doubt the problem is with the `convert()` function itself.  However, I don't believe your function will do what you're intending.  The function value probably isn't going to remember the culture used if you're returning a `datetime` since when converting *to* a `datetime` the third argument controls the *input* format only.  It will expect the out formatting to be done by the `SELECT` query.

Comment: You need to tell us how you are populating `@vMonth`, `@vDay`, etc. It's clear that somehow `@vMonth` is getting something > 12, or `@vDay` something > 31 (or > 28/29 for February, etc) or something is even more wrong than this (like `@vYear` is 9237823273239). But we can't tell you how or why that's happening if all we can see is your convert.

Comment: Bacon, that's what I want; I want it to treat the input as being in us-en format even if the system is set to British.

Comment: Aaron: unfortunately I can't post the full code, but I verified that if I run with input '1,2,3', then when it gets to the convert statement, the values of the variables (which are all varchar(255)s) are 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: But passing in `1,2,3` isn't us-en anything, it's just three numbers separated by commas. If you can't debug why certain sets of input parameters are causing this error, then you need to show us enough code so we can debug it for you. Otherwise this question is a non-starter.

Comment: I edited the question with a minimal code sample showing my problem.

Comment: What does "this does not" mean? Are you saying `select CONVERT(datetime,'01/02/03',101)` yields an error?

Comment: Yes; the result is: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when using 101 as the language, SQL Server expects the century to be in XXXX format. To handle 2-digit years correctly, you must use 1 as the language instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. No errors.

```
declare @mydate datetime = getdate()

declare @vMonth varchar(10), @vDay varchar(10), @vYear varchar(10)

set @vMonth = cast(DATEPART(mm, @mydate) as varchar(10))
set @vDay = cast(DATEPART(dd, @mydate) as varchar(10))
set @vYear = cast(DATEPART(YYYY, @mydate) as varchar(10))

select CONVERT(datetime, @vMonth+'/'+@vDay+'/'+@vYear, 101)
```

Result:

```
2015-01-09 00:00:00.000
```